# How to listen Data being transferred via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, keyboard-events, android-bluetooth

I am working on android app being developed for Kopin Golden-i device (wearable device). This device uses another application named **Companion App** which sends key strokes from mobile phone via Bluetooth.

Now lets come to question, I want to handle those keystrokes in my own application, however I have checked onKeyDown() and onKeyUp() methods of activity for the same, but these methods dint help me. So Now I am trying to get the data coming via Bluetooth but don't know is it possible or not. So please guide me is it possible to handle the data being transferred via Bluetooth if yes then please give me hint so I can achieve the required task. Your help would be appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. watch is working like this :
[image: Wearable working flow]

**You can check your event here like: DataEvent**

```
 public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
  for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {
    if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED &&
        event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath().equals("/image")) {
      DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem());
      Asset profileAsset = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getAsset("profileImage");
      Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromAsset(profileAsset);
      // Do something with the bitmap
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Accept the answer so , one can have information about the flow.